# Polymorphism base class pointers

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

Say I have two templated classes, one pure virtual parent and another that inherits from the parent. Both are templated to take a generic type and a functor. For example:

```
template<typename T, typename funct>
class pure_virtual{
     //pure virtual members
}
template<typename T, typename funct>
class child : public pure_virtual{
     //members
}
```

In my main, I want to create a pure_virtual pointer to my child class without the use of dynamic memory. For example:

```
int main(){
     pure_virtual<int*,my_functor>* p;
     child<int*,my_functor> c(my_functor);
     p = &c;
     return 0;
}
```

This implementation gives me a compile error stating that it cannot convert type child into type pure_virtual. Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong here? I know if I use dynamic allocation, this will work; however, I would really like to avoid it if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a compilable example:

```
template<typename T, typename funct>
class pure_virtual{
     //pure virtual members
};

template<typename T, typename funct>
class child : public pure_virtual<T,funct> {
  public:
     //members
     child(funct) { }
};

struct my_functor {};

int main(){
     pure_virtual<int*,my_functor>* p;
     my_functor f;
     child<int*,my_functor> c(f);
     p = &c;
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have fallen victim to a vexing parse. `child<int*,my_functor> c(my_functor)` does not declare a  `child<int*,my_functor>` object, but instead declares a function which takes a `my_functor` and returns a `child<int*,my_functor>`.

Such a function cannot be converted in to a `pure_virtual<int*,my_functor>*`.

To fix this, change that line to:

```
child<int*,my_functor> c((my_functor()));
```

Comment: This unfortunately created a new error. A fix, as described below, was to instantiate the functor. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

1)

```
class child : public pure_virtual< T, funct> {
...
```

2)

> child< int*,my_functor > c(my_functor);

If `my_functor` is a type, then you can't pass it to c-tor.